# insert same data into two field float

Tags: odoo

Please help, I have two columns, columns A and B (A and B of type float). so I want to make if I fill the value in column A and hit save, auto value I enter in column A will also appear in column B

I make like this

```
def _dept_count(self, cr, uid, ids,A,B,arg, context=None):
    result = {}
    for r in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
       B=0
       if r.deposit:
            B = A
       result[r.id] = A 
    return result

_columns = {
    'name': fields.many2one('res.partner','Partner'),
    'date':fields.date('Date of Deposit'),
    #'deposit': fields.function(_save_deposit, type='float',string='Deposit'),
    'available': fields.float('Available'),
    'note': fields.text('Description'),
}
```

but there is no response to anything. was not included in the database. please help

**P.S
his second was in the same database**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems on your code:

- `deposit` uses function `_save_deposit`, not `_dept_count`;
- `dept_count` returns a dict, and should return a float.

If you are trying to update `available` when `deposit` is changed, why not override the `create` and `write` methods instead?

Comment: sorry...I forget to change it haha..., so I must used **create and write** both of them ?

Comment: You will want to copy the `deposit` value on `create`. You might need to include some logic in the `write` method if the user is allowed to change the deposited amount later. You may need to correct, or at least just copy, the changed value.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `on_change` also to set the value of the alternate field .
But Apart from this you have two more Options fields.function and field. related ;)

Regards